# Kafka consumer is reading last committed offset on re-start (Java)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kakfa consumer for which ***enable.auto.commit*** is set to ***false***. Whenever I re-start my consumer application, it always reads the last committed offset again and then the next offsets.

For ex. Last committed offset is 50. When I restart consumer, it again reads offset 50 first and then the next offsets.

I am performing commitsync as shown below.

```
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets = new HashMap<>();
offsets.put(new TopicPartition("sometopic", partition), new OffsetAndMetadata(offset));
kafkaconsumer.commitSync(offsets);
```

I tried setting ***auto.offset.reset*** to ***earliest*** and ***latest*** but it is not changing the behavior.

Am I missing something here in consumer configuration ?

```
config.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "CLIENT_ID");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "GROUP_ID");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());
config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,CustomDeserializer.class.getName());
config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use `commitSync(offset)` you have to be careful and read its [Javadoc](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync-java.util.Map-):

> The committed offset should be the next message your application will consume, i.e. lastProcessedMessageOffset + 1.

If you don't add + 1 to the offset, it is expected that on next restart, the consumer will consume again the last message. As mentioned in the other answer, if you use `commitSync()` without any argument, you don't have to worry about that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to commit using `new OffsetAndMetadta(offset)`.  That's not the typical usage.

Here's an example from the documentation, under *Manual Offset Control*:

```
 List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
 while (true) {
     ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
     for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
         buffer.add(record);
     }
     if (buffer.size() >= minBatchSize) {
         insertIntoDb(buffer);
         consumer.commitSync();
         buffer.clear();
     }
 }
```

https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Notice how the `consumer.commitSync()` call is performed without any parameters.  It simply consumes, and it will commit to whatever was consumed up to that point.

Comment: This commit everything and you can't handle a finer offset commit such as, for example, if I read 10 messages and processing the 6th one throws an exception.. maybe I want to commit up to the offset relative to the 5th message, so that I don't handle the same messages more than once